# Ifstream returns empty string

Tags: ifstream, c++builder-6

The file is not empty, but `ifstream` returns an empty string.

Here is what I have tried:

```
std::ifstream ifs;
ifs.open("joke");
ifs >> ymjoke.c_str();
ShowMessage(ymjoke);
```

Here is a screenshot of the `ShowMessage()` window:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that `ymjoke` is declared as an `AnsiString`, yes?  Why are you reading into its `c_str()` pointer?  Did you pre-allocate `ymjoke`'s memory beforehand? I'm betting you did not. You are using the overloaded `operator>>` that reads into a `char[]` buffer, so it expects that buffer to be large enough to hold the text being read into it, eg:

```
AnsiString ymjoke;
ymjoke.SetLength(256); // or whatever size suits your need
std::ifstream ifs("joke");
ifs >> std::setw(ymjoke.Length()+1) >> ymjoke.c_str();
ShowMessage(ymjoke.c_str());
```

That said, the VCL has an overloaded `operator>>` for reading an `AnsiString` from a `std::istream`.  You just need to enable it manually, by adding `VCL_IOSTREAM` to the Conditionals list in your project options.  Then, you can use it like this:

```
AnsiString ymjoke;
std::ifstream ifs("joke");
ifs >> ymjoke;
ShowMessage(ymjoke);
```

Otherwise, read into a `std::string` instead, eg:

```
std::string ymjoke;
std::ifstream ifs("joke");
ifs >> ymjoke;
ShowMessage(ymjoke.c_str());
```